# Search in list of tuples

Tags: python

I extract a dataset row:

```
(u"[('x-xss-protection', '1; mode=block'), ('x-powered-by', 'PHP/5.4.21 ZendServer/6.2.0'), ('transfer-encoding', 'chunked'), ('expires', '0'), ('vary', 'Accept-Encoding'), ('server', 'nginx'), ('last-modified', 'Thu, 03 Dec 2015 10:20:02 GMT'), ('connection', 'keep-alive'), ('pragma', 'no-cache'), ('cache-control', 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, public'), ('date', 'Thu, 03 Dec 2015 10:20:02 GMT'), ('x-cached', 'EXPIRED'), ('content-type', 'text/html')]",)
```

I would like to find 'content-type'.
I tried dict, list, enumerate, str, ...
But nothing works: (

Comment: `x-xss-protection'` or `'x-xss-protection'`?

Comment: that's not a list of tuples. that's a single tuple with a string in it

Comment: 'x-xss-protection' , you're right. I deleted some data :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The string in your tuple looks like a list, I'd suggest use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to convert it to a *real list*, and then convert it to a dict (simply run `dict()` function), and use `'content-type'` as the key to access the `'text/html'` (value):

```
import ast
t = (u"[('x-xss-protection', '1; mode=block'), ('x-powered-by', 'PHP/5.4.21 ZendServer/6.2.0'), ('transfer-encoding', 'chunked'), ('expi res', '0'), ('vary', 'Accept-Encoding'), ('server', 'nginx'), ('last-modified', 'Thu, 03 Dec 2015 10:20:02 GMT'), ('connection', 'keep-alive '), ('pragma', 'no-cache'), ('cache-control', 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, public'), ('date', 'Thu, 03 Dec 2015 10:20:02 GMT '), ('x-cached', 'EXPIRED'), ('content-type', 'text/html')]",)
dict(ast.literal_eval(t[0]))['content-type']
```

Output:

```
'text/html'
```

Comment: If you store this type of data in database, this is this method to access it ?

Comment: @Anonymus: If the data in database is like your example: Yes. Otherwise, you can ask a new question about it.